# Double Brace Initialization in java

Tags: java, performance, refactoring

I found in this site http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/20/double-brace-initialization-in-java/
a new way to start my collection

I always have a doubt about java

Can I have one structure like `with do` in Delphi, to make my code be like this

```
        Set<String> params = new HashSet<String>() {
        {
            add("param one");
            add("param two");
            add("param three");
            add("param four");
        }
    };
```

And where can I find other interesting practices like that showed in site?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested the code? I don't think it will work.

Comment: @Tareq: It does work. It just looks odd because most people forgot about initializer blocks.

Comment: Not a good idea though

Comment: As nice as it is to keep the code short, one should be aware that this use of double-brace initialization creates an anonymous class. This means that it actually changes the runtime type of the collection. This can lead to unexpected behavior with serialization (when the class is not available when deserializing for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People come up with great new ways to solve problems in Java all the time. But there are only few places where you can actually find compilations of such tricks.

A good place to start is to use frameworks like [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/get-started) and [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) because they contains state-of-the-art tricks that will make your life much easier (and your code smaller and safer after a while).